# Regular expression to match format

Tags: python, regex, spotfire

I have a file of names formatted as follow:

```
Last, First Middle Initial
```

In some instances the individual may not have a middle initial

```
Last, First
```

I would like to use a regular expression to change the order to

```
First Middle, Last name
```

or

```
First, Last Name (when there is no middle initial)
```

Could someone please help with the expressions that could accomplish this?

How could I set up my conditional fields for these cases using regex? I want to set up an if function where if the name field format is equal to of the two possibilities, it will use the respective expression to rearrange the name. I am using Spotfire client to perform this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Implement:

```
import re
R = re.compile(r"(\w+),\s+(\w+)(\s*\w*)")

def convert(s):
    return R.sub(r"\2\3, \1", s)
```

And test:

```
assert convert("Last, First Middle") == "First Middle, Last"
assert convert("Last, First") == "First, Last"
```